# Adding JFace wizard pages after addPages() was called?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, jface, wizard

i am trying to create a jface wizard.
In my wizard i have my "startpage". The options i choose in my "startpage" depending on how many pages will follow. But in my opinion its not possible to do that. Because the ***addPages()*** method getting called after the wizard was started. The ***addPage()*** method is private. But i need to add my pages there, because when i do it somewhere else, the ***createControl(Composite parent)*** don't getting called.

Is there any solution how to solve that problem?
I thought about writing a own method sth. like this:

```
public void addNewPage() {
Page page = new Page("pagename");
page.createControl(parent);
page.setDescription("");}
...
```

But it doesn't work.
Do you guys have any solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could add all your pages in the wizard `addPages` and then override `getNextPage` to control which pages is displayed when Next is pressed.

If that is not enough you can always write your own implementation of the `IWizard` interface.

Comment: Well at the start of the wizard i don't even know yet which (and how much) pages i need (including content). So it seems there is no suitable solution. Thanks anyway i gonna try to write my own implementation now ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by overriding `org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard.getNextPage` to return a new page if conditions are met (`conditionForMorePages` in the snippet below):

```
@Override
public IWizardPage getNextPage() {
   IWizardPage nextPage = super.getNextPage(page);
   if (nextPage == null) {
      if (conditionForMorePages){
         // we need an additional page.
         IWizardPage nextPage = new MyAdditionalPage();
      }
   }
   return nextPage;
}
```

If your wizard start with only one page, "back" and "next" buttons do not appear by default. If there is a chance you have more steps coming up dynamically, you want to display the navigation buttons. You can do so by setting the proper flag using the API

```
public void setForcePreviousAndNextButtons(boolean b)
```